# How can I listen the Kafka stream from the start?

Tags: apache-kafka, memgraphdb

I've started the Kafka stream from `mgconsole` using this code:

```
CREATE KAFKA STREAM music_stream
TOPICS music-stars
TRANSFORM music_books.music_stars
CONSUMER_GROUP randomseed141234
BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS 'localhost:9093'
CREDENTIALS {'sasl.username':'public',
                'sasl.password':'public',
                'security.protocol':'SASL_PLAINTEXT',
                'sasl.mechanism':'PLAIN'};
```

I want to listen all of the messages from beginning. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilites to consume a kafka topic. If you just want to take a look for debugging purposes I suggest using a tool like [this vscode-extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jeppeandersen.vscode-kafka) where you can just input the connection info.

If you want to consume programmatically, there are many connectors for Kafka, for example this [nice npm-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafkajs).

But as far as I understand, you would use Memgraph to consume streaming data into your databases. So there is no need to consume the data from the stream - Memgraph does the consuming and you can query the db as usual. Take a look at [memgraphs-docs for stream-processing with kafka](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/2.1.1/tutorials/graph-stream-processing-with-kafka) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

When using a Kafka stream, you can manually set the offset of the next consumed message with a call to the query procedure `mg.kafka_set_stream_offset`:

```
CALL mg.kafka_set_stream_offset(stream_name, offset)
```

An offset of `-1` denotes the start of the stream, i.e., the beginning offset available for the given topic/partition.

An offset of `-2` denotes the end of the stream, i.e., for each topic/partition, its logical end such that only the next produced message will be consumed.

So the exact code for your case should be:

```
CALL mg.kafka_set_stream_offset(music_stream, -1)
```